# Python: Using oswalk in first function to find files, pass name, then trying to open in second function

Tags: python, function, argument-passing

I am trying to use two functions to find files and process them, the output of which, ultimately, will be sent to a SQlite3 database.  I have the second part working when NOT a function, but for this, need to enter the name of each file to be processed.  I want it automated, hence the first function with oswalk.  However, when I add the first function, which finds the files and returns them to the second function, something is going wrong.  In the code posted, I just want to test that the files are being passed and can be opened and read one at a time.

Notes about what is happening and pointers to the output (which will be pasted below the code) are hashed out in the code below.

```
import os
import fnmatch

def findFiles (path, filter):
    Files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
           Files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return Files

def fastq2SQlite(Files):
    for file in Files:
        print file    ## At this point, I have a list of files.  See "A" below.  

        with open(file, 'r'):  ##If this block is then added, it's evident that the files shown 
                               ##in "A" are not being recognized as files.  Output is "A" 
                               ##transposed, each line a letter of a file name.
            for line in file:
                print line
```

Output "A"
C:/Users/Documents/JKC10/test.txt
C:/Users/Documents/JKC10/test2.txt
C:/Users/Documents/JKC10/test3.txt
None

I have even unsuccessfully tried to get the files to be read by modifying them so that their names become (example):
'C:/Users/Documents/JKC10/test_out.txt'

by adding a block that looks like:

```
def fastq2SQlite(Files):
    for file in Files:
        f = "'" + file + "'"
```

Comment: use `file.read()` in the second last line: `for line in file:`     Instead use `for line in file.read()`

Comment: I get this error:  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' So, it's not seeing the files as 'files'.  I even added that bit to the part where I rename them as f (so have quotes) but that gives the error "IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename:"

Comment: use `with open(file, 'r') as dummy_file` and for line in `dummy_file.read()`

Comment: Okay...If I change that a bit to 'with open(file, 'r') as dummy_file' and then 'for line in dummy_file:' it works.  Woot!  Having the 'dummy_file.read()' put each letter of the files on its own line.
THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import fnmatch

def findFiles (path, filter):
    Files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
           Files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return Files

def fastq2SQlite(Files):
    for file_ in Files:
        print file_    

        with open(file_, 'r') as dummy_file:

            for line in dummy_file:
                print line
```

You should also avoid using the keywords like `file`, etc. as variable names, It overrides the original object and can cause some serious issues, Just a good programming practice.